# Canonot resolve symbol fasterxml

Tags: java, android, android-studio

以下に示したコードで同期をとると、イベントログに下記Errorが出力されます。

何か設定が足らないのでしょうか？

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8] on root project 'LoginActivity' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

#### ソースコード

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.example.loginactivity.ui.login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.example.loginactivity.R;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
```

**build gradle(:app)**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0-alpha02'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation  'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
    implementation  'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build Gradle (LoginAcitivity) に以下の記述をしていたのが原因だったようです。
コメントアウトしたら ReBuild できました。

```
implement  'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'
```